# Java Discord4j how to send message to channel REST API?

Tags: java, discord, discord4j

I try to send message to channel

```
GatewayDiscordClient gatewayDiscordClient = DiscordClient
                .builder("TOKEN")
                .build()
                .login()
                .block();

gatewayDiscordClient.rest().getChannelById(Snowflake.of("ChannelId")).createMessage("p");
```

But channel doesn't displaythe message in history. How can I fix that?

Comment: P.s I should add .block() and it works. Question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Discord4J utilizes the [Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) framework which is "lazily executed".

You must `.subscribe()` or `.block()` on publishers (usually a `Mono<T>` or `Flux<T>`).

So, to get your code to create the message:
`gatewayDiscordClient.rest().getChannelById(Snowflake.of("ChannelId")).createMessage("p").subscribe();`

I would advise however, to not use the `RestX` classes unless you are not using the gateway (which, in your question, is being used). Rest classes generally provide less of the helpful abstractions D4J offers and is meant to be used internally by the library or for a webserver, not a bot connected to the gateway.

To send a message without using rest classes your code would look like this:

```
client.getChannelById(channelIdHere)
    .ofType(MessageChannel.class)
    .flatMap(channel -> channel.createMessage("Your content here"))
    .subscribe();
```